# layout in android studio

Tags: android, layout

I get confused when it comes to layout in android.

I am trying to get a layout similar as picture below where the textfield is all the way to the right side and the text somehow align in the middle or so. can someone help me get the layout as the attached image?

[layout image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ah8ajk9lbwsrhvc/Screenshot_2015-09-27-16-27-49.png?dl=0)

[image]

also, can someone figure out what is the name of the text and size in the attached image. i like it and would like to use it in my app.

I appreciate if someone can post some xml code to get layout in the pic (link attached).

A simple example with two or 3 text and corresponding textfield align as the pic shows will be enough.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have provided here basic layout that contains first three rows of layout..

Please try this and add all your next entities in and let me know if you stuck somewhere..!!

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_amount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_description"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_tax"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_amount"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Tax"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.!!

Comment: AndiGeeky or anyone who can help, how can make the keyboard appear when the button in the amount section is press? basically what i am trying to do is that when the button with the star is press, it will bring up the virtual keyboard so that i can type a number and then the number is display in the amount textfield. any idea how to do that?

Comment: @yoohoo : If this answer worked for you then please accept it so others can lead to best answer..!! Thanks.

Comment: @yoohoo : For second query please add new question so that more people can help you..!!

Comment: @andigreeky,  how do i accept the answer?  i am new to stackoverflow, do i have to press any button and where is the screen can i accept the answer? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Help" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```